# Jhipster package.json issue in Mac

Tags: json, macos, jhipster

**OS: 10.9.2**
I am using jhipster generator, and it seems to be an issue with package.json in mac, do we have any work around?

Below is the error:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, utime '/Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call utimes
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, utime '/Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/inherits/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/inherits/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/inherits/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call utimes
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/promised-io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/win-spawn
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/typedarray/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/typedarray/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/typedarray/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/get-urls
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/astral-pass
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/get-stdin
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: /Users/hmajumdar/.npm/tape/0.2.2/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! file /Users/hmajumdar/.npm/tape/0.2.2/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/win-spawn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/get-urls
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/get-stdin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/output.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/output.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/output.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)




1910 error error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/inherits'
1910 error error rolling back  grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.9.0 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/inherits']
1910 error error rolling back   errno: 53,
1910 error error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
1910 error error rolling back   path: '/Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster/node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/inherits' }
1911 error Failed to parse json
1911 error Unexpected end of input
1912 error File: /Users/hmajumdar/.npm/tape/0.2.2/package/package.json
1913 error Failed to parse package.json data.
1913 error package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
1913 error
1913 error This is not a bug in npm.
1913 error Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
1914 error System Darwin 13.1.0
1915 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
1916 error cwd /Users/hmajumdar/Work/sandbox/jhipster
1917 error node -v v0.10.28
1918 error npm -v 1.4.9
1919 error file /Users/hmajumdar/.npm/tape/0.2.2/package/package.json
1920 error code EJSONPARSE
1921 verbose exit [ 1, true
```

Comment: If everything you need is installed globally, this may be an issue with the network.  I'm running 10.9.2 OSX and haven't run into this in the .16 release of JHipster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was due to the way NPM was being installed in my machine, I cleared some caches and reinstalled npm. That solved it.